# Access Google-drive API from google-Drive public folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to run the example shown [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js#step_2_set_up_the_sample) from a google drive public folder, but I get an 400 (Bad Request) all the time.

I Just't to know if it is possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Here is the output that I got if I launch the example at my home server

```
GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=542813617254.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&immediate=true&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fda515.no-ip.org&proxy=oauth2relay389420508&response_type=token&state=449660269&authuser=0 400 (Bad Request) cb=gapi.loaded_0:126
(anonymous function) cb=gapi.loaded_0:126
_.yl cb=gapi.loaded_0:122
(anonymous function) cb=gapi.loaded_0:121
(anonymous function) cb=gapi.loaded_0:120
_.vc cb=gapi.loaded_0:57
_.Eb
```

This is what I Get from my public folder in google Drive

```
GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=542813617254.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&immediate=true&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogledrive.com&proxy=oauth2relay247984856&response_type=token&state=819470227&authuser=0 400 (Bad Request) cb=gapi.loaded_0:126
(anonymous function) cb=gapi.loaded_0:126
_.yl cb=gapi.loaded_0:122
(anonymous function) cb=gapi.loaded_0:121
(anonymous function) cb=gapi.loaded_0:120
_.vc cb=gapi.loaded_0:57
_.Eb
```

I checked the o2Auth and it looks fine

Authorized Redirect URIs

http://da515.no-ip.org/oauth2callback

http://gdriv.es/danielo515/oauth2callback

Authorized JavaScript Origins

https://da515.no-ip.org/

<strike>I don't figue what is wrong</strike>
Ok, I know the problem, what I don't know what the exact problem was.

For my home server was just wrong direction, https, or http, I'm not sure what is correct, because I can acces using both.

But, with the google Drive public folder I have the same problem, because I can't add the googledrive direction to the auth string

Comment: Check the complete response, it should tell you why the request is invalid

Comment: YEs, But i don't figure how to fix it. I will add it to the main question

Comment: Visit https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=542813617254.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&immediate=true&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fda515.no-ip.org&proxy=oauth2relay389420508&response_type=token&state=449660269&authuser=0, if the error is "origin mismatch" that means that the website running this JS code doesn't match the one you specified in the APIs Console

Comment: Yes, you're Right, I got that message from my Home server, but when i try this from google Drive publif folder I get something similar. Anyway I will add it to the main question

Comment: Why I can't add https://googledrive.com/host/My_FOLDER_ID/ to the o2Auth string list?

Comment: i know this one is old, but did you managed to get this working? need same now. thanks